# I can't edit a message from discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make a countdown timer that uses a command `/timer minutes seconds` where the user chooses how long the countdown will be. I want the bot to send the timer as a reply to the command which I've successfully done. However, I also want the message to update along with the timer.

I can `console.log` the timer and it works but I can't figure out how to make the bot edit its own message. I have tried to just simply edit the bots' message without the timer but with no success.

Code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder,} = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed, Channel, Message, MessageReaction, Client } = require('discord.js');
const { Countdown } = require('countdown');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("timer")
        .setDescription("Starta en timer")
        .addNumberOption((option) => option.setName('minutes').setDescription('Set amount of minutes').setRequired(true))
        .addNumberOption((option) => option.setName('seconds').setDescription('Set amount of seconds').setRequired(true)),
        
    execute: async ({ client, interaction}) => {
            let minutes = interaction.options.getNumber("minutes")
            let seconds = interaction.options.getNumber("seconds")

            let minutesToSeconds = minutes * 60;
            let time = minutesToSeconds + seconds;
            let duration = time;

            let getTime = "Timer: " + duration

            let interval = setInterval((timerMessage) => {
                duration--;
                if(duration == 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    getTime ="Timer is done"
                }
                getTime.edit("Timer: " + duration)
                console.log(duration)
            }, 1000)
            
            await interaction.reply(
                getTime
            );
    },
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you get if you try to edit the message?

Comment: I have tried to use the .edit() function in the setInterval, which exists in discord.js documentation, but it replies with ".edit() is not a function".

Comment: The code in your post doesn't show any functions using `.edit()` are you sure you have the right code posted in your question?

Comment: I had indeed posted a version without the edit function, now it's updated

Comment: Variable `getTime` is just a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). The `.edit()` method is only accessible if this variable is an instance of [Message (Discord.js)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `interaction.editReply()` to update the interaction message after an x amount of time using your timer. This is an example of how you can use it:

```js
bot.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    let seconds = 10;

    let timerMessage = "Timer is started.";
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        seconds--;

        timerMessage = `Timer: ${seconds} seconds left.`;

        if(seconds === 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
            interaction.editReply(`Timer has finished!`);
        } else {
            interaction.editReply(timerMessage)
        }
    }, 1000);

    await interaction.reply({
        content: timerMessage
    });
});
```

This also works if `ephemeral` is set to `true`. Note that this is a raw example, and you should adjust the code by your needs.